# Java JRE 1.7 JCombobox<E> setSelectedItem(Object anObject) is not working properly?

Tags: swing, java

Just see the below code snippet,

```
    String[] choices = {"Apple", "Banana", "Custard"};  
    JComboBox<String> fruits = new JComboBox<String>(choices);        
    fruits.setSelectedItem("Custard");
```

It throws null pointer exception. see below,

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
     at java.awt.EventQueue.getCurrentEventImpl(Unknown Source)
     at java.awt.EventQueue.getCurrentEvent(Unknown Source)
     at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireActionEvent(Unknown Source)
     at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedItem(Unknown Source)
```

The same problem happening for setSelectedIndex() also. Please suggest good workaround for this problem or Suggest me, if there is any problem with Java JRE  1.7.

Comment: We can't tell the problem based on 3 lines of code. There muse be some other code causing the problem. Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. Chances are while you create the SSCCE you will find your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>        at java.awt.EventQueue.getCurrentEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>        at java.awt.EventQueue.getCurrentEvent(Unknown Source)
>        at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireActionEvent(Unknown Source)
>        at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedItem(Unknown Source)

from

```
String[] choices = {"Apple", "Banana", "Custard"};  
JComboBox<String> fruits = new JComboBox<String>(choices);        
fruits.setSelectedItem("Custard");
```

is possible to generating only in the case that is added `Action/ItemListener` before `setSelectedItem` is called (debug that, whats `XxxListener` firing), change to

```
String[] choices = {"Apple", "Banana", "Custard"};  
JComboBox<String> fruits = new JComboBox<String>(choices);        
fruits.setSelectedItem("Custard");
fruits.addAction / ItemListener(new Action / ItemListener)
```

and the same issue in Java6

> @sanjay wrote if i add that actionlistener to the combobox. it gives
>   the same error. But it working properly in java 1.6 without that
>   Combobox generic type.

- not, I'm not talking about, you can to generating this exception from this code

  1. comment code line (//)mainComboBox.setSelectedItem("Fruit");
  2. and uncomment //mainComboBox.setSelectedItem("Shape");

then this code firing same exception, quite common issue for JComboBox, same issue in Java6 (by removing Generics from JComboBox definition)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class FruitAndVedg extends JFrame implements ActionListener, ItemListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4L;
    private JComboBox<String> mainComboBox;
    private JComboBox<String> subComboBox;
    private ArrayList item;
    private Hashtable<Object, Object> subItems = new Hashtable<>();

    public FruitAndVedg() {
        item = new ArrayList();
        item.add("Select Item");
        item.add("Fruit");
        item.add("Vedg");
        String[] items = {"Select Item", "Color", "Shape", "Fruit"};
        mainComboBox = new JComboBox<>(items/*item.toArray()*/);
        mainComboBox.setSelectedItem("Fruit");
        mainComboBox.addActionListener(this);
        mainComboBox.addItemListener(this);
        //mainComboBox.setSelectedItem("Shape");
        add(mainComboBox, BorderLayout.WEST);
        subComboBox = new JComboBox<>();
        subComboBox.setPrototypeDisplayValue("XXXXXXXXXX");
        add(subComboBox, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        String[] subItems1 = {"Select Fruit", "Apple", "Plum"};
        subItems.put(items, subItems1);
        String[] subItems2 = {"Select Vedg", "Carrot", "Peas"};
        subItems.put(items, subItems2);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        String item = (String) mainComboBox.getSelectedItem();
        Object o = subItems.get(item);
        if (o == null) {
            subComboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel());
        } else {
            subComboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel((String[]) o));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie) {
        if (ie.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            if (ie.getSource() == mainComboBox) {
                if (mainComboBox.getSelectedIndex() != 0) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new FruitAndVedg();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: if i add that actionlistener to the combobox. it gives the same error. But it working properly in java 1.6 without that Combobox generic type.

Comment: Yeah mKorbel..its working fine..But could you please explain little bit brief on this issue..?

Comment: Listener firing an event to GUI that isn't displayable in this moment, then there are two options, setSelectedItem before any Listener is added to JComboBox, or after JFrame.setVisible(true) is called, but Listener can firing an event, depends of what do you want to do

Comment: Thanks mKOrbel, Just i tried with removing listeners from ur code. But still working without that listeners. any idea.?

Answer (score 0):

Here is workaround that might solve the NPE

```
String[] items = {"Select Item", "Color", "Shape", "Fruit"};
mainComboBox = new JComboBox<>(items/*item.toArray()*/);

SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        mainComboBox.setSelectedItem("Fruit");
    }
});

mainComboBox.addActionListener(this);
mainComboBox.addItemListener(this);
```